# Two versions of the same locator in automation testing: one works, the other causes numerous errors

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

There is a list box that contains three options: "In Progress", "Complete", and "Clear Status".

When I call:

```
page_object.zs_out_btn(driver).click();
new Select(page_object.zs_out_btn(driver)).selectByVisibleText("In Progress");
```

...this works perfectly. This clicks the dropdown button, and selects 'In Progress'.

After this is where I start having issues. I have two versions of the same thing I am trying select in the sense that one works and the other doesn't; I am not running both of these at the same time.

```
page_object.zs_out_btn(driver).click();
//new Select(page_object.zs_out_btn(driver)).selectByVisibleText("Complete");
//new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("zs-status-select"))).selectByVisibleText("Complete");
```

The second line doesn't work. The third line does. I used Katalon and two other tools to verify that this path is indeed valid. They even work inside of those tools and despite hundreds of attempts at sampling this, it always gives this id. byClass couldn't be found even through manual definition. The HTML for this looks like this:

```
<select id="zs-status-select" class="form-control" style=""><option>In Progress</option><option>Complete</option><option value="">Clear Status (Blank)</option></select>
```

The way that I defined the second line in POM is such:

```
public WebElement zs_out_btn(WebDriver driver) {
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("zs-outpost-select"));
        return element;
    }
```

What I am seeing is that TestNG doesn't report this as a failure and goes directly to my `@AfterTest`. So I disabled this to see if it would just hang on that element and it did. I tried implicit, explicit, and even a thread.sleep(I know I'm not supposed to use this, it is only for testing) waits to make sure everything on page was loaded and to give the driver time to find it.

Depending on how many times I run this, every now and then it will work, sometimes the browser will just time out and quit on its own even with the @AfterTest disabled, sometimes eclipse oxygen will freeze and give some errors that I've never seen before then quit. After restarting eclipse numerous times, it will start to work and then come back to the same issue I am having.

So, I reinstalled eclipse, rebuilt the project from scratch, three times, included the correct libraries for selenium and TestNG. Same behavior. I am able to run all my other tests perfectly fine.

Why is this particular element, so troublesome and why would it force the browser or eclipse to time out and close? Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work? does it throws any exception/error or it doesn't do any action?

Comment: @GaurangShah that's the problem. It's different every time. Sometimes it will not do the action on screen: selected the element from the drop down list but TestNG will say it was a success. Sometimes it will throw an exception saying that it can't find that element. Sometimes eclipse will crash. Sometimes the browser will crash. Sometimes it will give back errors relating to TestNG with line numbers that don't exist. When I try to copy a stack trace or tell eclipse to just write it to a text file, it just crashes. I've never seen this kind of behavior before.

Comment: @GaurangShah what's even weirder is that I can't generate the TestNG XML file from the failure the few times it does happen.

Comment: And now I'm getting NoSuchWindowEception. I literally haven't touched it. It ran fine about an hour ago. Ran it again that error disappeared and now it's telling me it can't find that id.

Comment: Now I'm getting disconnected from my remote session because of a protocol error 0x112f. I really think this is an eclipse/java issue.

Comment: Do you have the latest driver and browser combination? Are there any iframes present?

Comment: Found my own solution. The problem is eclipse oxygen. Installed the latest version of Netbeans. Everything works fine now. No crashing and no problems.

Comment: @Grasshopper Yes actually. Each time I made a new project, I downloaded a new zip file, new workspace, new everything. Firefox is new and the other tests run fine when eclipse decides not to crash. There are no inline frames that I can find.